# Why div's size automatically reduced even if i gave the size

Tags: html, division

I have defined size of div's in percentages, but i don't why it is getting reduced automatically. Even defining the height and width in the pixels isn't helping. The issue remains the same. Kindly go through all the code. Here's the code.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*, java.io.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Assessments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Styles.css" type="text/css">
<style>
li {
    float: left;
    font-size:20px;

}
#headul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #3d4e4a;
}
#bheadul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #23302d;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button
{
    float: left;
    font-size:20px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background:url(Images/Backgroud.jpg); background-size: 1370px 1000px;height:100%;width:100%;min-height: 100%;min-width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden;">

        <div id="head" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;background-color:#ffffff;height:56px;">
        <ul id="headul">
                    <li style="font-size:30px"><a href="Index.jsp">Quizilla</a></li>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <li style="float:right;"><a href="Contact.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right;"><a href="about.jsp">About Us</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right;"><a href="Features.jsp">Features</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right;"><a href="Index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                </ul>
    </div><br><br><br>
        <div id="lowerhead" style="position:absolute;left:0;color:#ffffff;height:40px;">
        <ul id="bheadul">
            <% if((session.getAttribute("email"))!=null) {  %>
            <li style="float:left;"><a href="UserHome.jsp">My Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserProfile.jsp">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserScores.jsp">My Scores</a></li>
            <li><a href="Assessments.jsp">Assessments</a></li>
            <%} %>
            <% if((session.getAttribute("email"))==null)
                response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
                %>
            <%for(int i=0;i<67;i++)
                out.println("&nbsp;"); %>
            <li style="float:right;"><a href="Index.jsp?logout=success">Logout</a></li>&nbsp;
            <li style="float:right;"><a href="ChangePassword.jsp">Change Password</a></li>&nbsp;
        </ul>
        </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div style="height:730px;width:1143px;background-color:#f7fcfa;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;margin-top:auto;box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
        <div style="float:left;align-content: center;height:8%;width:25%;background-color:#E7F5F1"><br>
            <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:auto;">My Assessments</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="height:8%;width:74.8%;float:right; border:1px solid #000000">
        <form name="create" action="CreateQuiz.jsp">
            <div style="height:100%; width:80%; border:1px solid #000000;float:left;margin-top:auto;">
            <input style="margin-top:10px;font-size:16px;float:right;" type="text" name="Test_Name" placeholder="Test Title" required/></div>
            <div style="height:100%; width:19.5%;float:right; border:1px solid #000000;margin-top:auto;">
            <input type="submit"style="float:right;"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div style="height:8%;width:74.8%;float:right; border:1px solid #000000">
            <div style="float:left;height:100%;width:50%;"><h3>Test Name</h3></div>
            <div style="float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;"><h3>Number of Questions</h3></div>
            <div style="float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;"><h3>Maximum Marks</h3></div>

        </div>
        <%getTest(session,out); %>
        </div>
<%!
    public static void getTest(HttpSession session,JspWriter out)
    {
        String username = (String)session.getAttribute("email");
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     //creating connection with the database 
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                       ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizilla","root","manish123");
        String query="select test_name, number, max_marks from test_table where email='"+username+"'";
        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String test_name = rs.getString("test_name");
            int number= rs.getInt("number");
            int max_marks=rs.getInt("max_marks");
            String div="<div style= 'height:8%;width:74.8%;float:right;'>";
            out.println(div);
            String div1="<div style= 'float:left;height:100%;width:50%;'>";
            String div2="<div style= 'float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;'>";
            String div3="<div style= 'float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;'>";
            String field1="<pre style='font-size:18px'>"+test_name+"</pre>";
            String field2="<pre style='font-size:18px'> "+number+"</pre>";
            String field3="<pre style='font-size:18px'> "+max_marks+"</pre>";
            out.println(div1);
            out.println(field1+"</div>");
            out.println(div2);
            out.println(field2+"</div>");
            out.println(div3);
            out.println(field3+"</div></div><br><br>");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: You are using two separate divs inside form tag. That is causing all the problems.

Comment: can't i use div in form tag?

Comment: Yes you can. But that div's behavior. I tried all to solve your problem. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest an tag inside another, the "%" value refers to outer tag (that is nesting the target tag)

If I understood it correctly, this might solve the problem.

Comment: Yes you understand absolutely correct but as you can see i have given the height of div 100%, thats why i am asking this

Comment: When you say _"it is getting reduced automatically"_, do you mean that it changes the size when you resize the screen?

Comment: No i mean i have given the div's size lets suppose 100px and the text box's size if 50px, the div's size is automatically becomes 50px although in the code it is 100px

Comment: Can you post the **entire** html code (css, etc.)? It seems a bit strange for me.